# xlwings recently stopped getting live data from excel via Range

Tags: python, excel, null, range, xlwings

I was running a script to get data from excel for over a year using the Xlwings range command like so...
list=Range('A1:D10').value

Suddenly, it stopper working.  I had changed nothing in the code nor the system, other than maybe installing another network card.

This is the error when trying to use the Range assignment now.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\python32\fetcher.py", line 61, in <module>
    listFull = getComData()
  File "G:\python32\fetcher.py", line 38, in getComData
    listFull=Range('A4:H184').value
  File "G:\python32\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 1490, in __init__
    impl = apps.active.range(cell1).impl
  File "G:\python32\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 439, in range
    return Range(impl=self.impl.range(cell1, cell2))
  File "G:\python32\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 457, in range
    xl1 = self.xl.Range(arg1)
  File "G:\python32\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 341, in xl
    self._xl = get_xl_app_from_hwnd(self._hwnd)
  File "G:\python32\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 251, in get_xl_app_from_hwnd
    disp = COMRetryObjectWrapper(Dispatch(p))
  File "G:\python32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 96, in Dispatch
    return __WrapDispatch(dispatch, userName, resultCLSID, typeinfo, clsctx=clsctx)
  File "G:\python32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 37, in __WrapDispatch
    klass = gencache.GetClassForCLSID(resultCLSID)
  File "G:\python32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 180, in GetClassForCLSID
    mod = GetModuleForCLSID(clsid)
  File "G:\python32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 223, in GetModuleForCLSID
    mod = GetModuleForTypelib(typelibCLSID, lcid, major, minor)
  File "G:\python32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 259, in GetModuleForTypelib
    mod = _GetModule(modName)
  File "G:\python32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 622, in _GetModule
    mod = __import__(mod_name)
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Comment: I have had this kind of thing happen when either I have changed Python version, or MS Office has auto-updated Excel. You might need to re-create the `gencache` python wrapper for Excel. Maybe try re-installing the xlwings package or the win32com package or both. Or you can look for and delete the generated python files: you might find them under the user AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\x.x\ ... but that directory can be different depending on configuration. This will force win32com to regenerate the wrappers.

Comment: Extremely helpful!  It was deleting the appdata cache!